# How to import framework file without cocoapods?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

My project is `React Native` and I try to add native framework file to my project when I clean and build project I get the error

`Framework not found BRPtouchPrinterLit`

Here is what I try

Step 1:

drag the framework file under my `Frameworks folder` and then check Link Binary With Libraries include it.

[image]

Step 2:

type `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks/` on Framework Search Paths:

[image]

then Clean and Build the project get the error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/morton.hsu/PureIosProject/testIosBrother/ios/Frameworks/'
ld: framework not found BRPtouchPrinterKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What step I miss it?

I download the sdk from this link
https://support.brother.com/g/b/agreement.aspx?dlid=dlfp100621_000&c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on

Comment: Have you checked out this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking ?

Comment: I don't have the xcodeproject to drag. It just a native sdk, I want to write some native code to let React Native use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks** with the flag **Recursive**.
I wrote a custom module for the company, and you can view my documentation. This custom module have inner framework and I link this framework to the main project.

https://github.com/Hardy1207/RNOkay

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/morton.hsu/PureIosProject/testIosBrother/ios/Frameworks'` when I try Recursive the root.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like the correct way to import the SDK, next error is another problem. I will open it on another question. Thanks for your help.